# PIP not working in Pythonxy?

Tags: python-2.7, pip, pythonxy

I am using Pythonxy (have uninstalled all old instances of Python) and it has pip as a standard plugin as per the document page https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/wiki/StandardPlugins

But when i use pip commands it fails. Can anybody kindly please figure out the mistake I am making?

P.S. Pip used to work well under Python before I moved to Pythonxy

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Imported NumPy 1.8.0, SciPy 0.13.3, Matplotlib 1.3.1
+ guidata 1.6.1, guiqwt 2.3.1
Type "scientific" for more details.
>>> pip freeze
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip freeze
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> pip install numpy
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install numpy
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PIP` has never worked that way.
Use a command line i.e. `BASH` and not `Python Interpreter`.
Sure that

```
pip install numpy
```

is invalid Python statement.  You can use mentioned command from your shell.